# Karate regex giving error - reason: not a string

Tags: karate

I have written a small scenario where I need to check a json key value to be any integer number. So this is my test step in Karate DSL:

```
When method get
* print response
Then match response contains { numberOfElements: '#regex [0-9]+' }
```

When run, i get error:

> path: $.numberOfElements, actual: 8, expected: '#regex [0-9]+', reason: not a string at ✽.Then match response contains { numberOfElements: '#regex [0-9]+' }

Any ideas what could be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For validating a JSON value with `integer` type it should be `'#number'`

```
#numberOfElements = 8
Then match response contains { numberOfElements: '#number' }
```

Your approaching will work only to check if the JSON value with `string` type contains all numbers.

```
#numberOfElements = '8'
Then match response contains { numberOfElements: '#regex [0-9]+' }
```

refer [fuzzy matching](https://github.com/intuit/karate#fuzzy-matching)